# Do bootable linux USB drives need to be safely ejected?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, xfce, bootable

I recently created a bootable Mint Xfce environment on a USB drive. After booting up and using it a few times, it stopped storing panel preferences I had made and, after some digging, I realized it had become corrupted.

So whilst running off a bootable USB drive, does it need to be safely removed before shutdown? Or does shutting down safely eject the USB drive?

Comment: I wouldn't remove the USB while the live system is running (although I'm not sure if it would cause a problem to do so). Shutting down the live session and then removing the USB should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I never remove it during boot, always wait for successful shut down, which is why I'm wondering if there are any other steps to safely removing the USB prior to shutdown as i'm wondering how this USB became corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some rare exceptions (where the booted system is actually running from RAM instead of the flash drive), you actually need to not remove the drive prior to trying to shut down.

There are three general cases of bootable flash drives for Linux:

1. Those which boot into a live environment that loses all changes when you shut down.
2. Those which boot into a regular environment stored on the flash drive which have changes persist when you shut down.
3. Those which work like the first case, but copy all their data into RAM during boot and then run from RAM instead of the drive.

In the first case, removing the flash drive may cause the system to hang because it can't access files it needs.  Most of these systems won't show an option to completely remove the flash drive (though if you have other partitions on the same flash drive, you will usually see options to eject those, though doing so isn't necessary just like you don't need to eject a flash drive prior to shutdown of a regular system).

In the second case, you will not only probably cause the system to hang, you may additionally have any of the other issues typically related to removing a flash drive that's being written to.  Fortunately, such systems usually prevent you from removing it on the software side (but you can still pull it out physically if you want of course).

In the third case, you can actually directly remove the flash drive whenever you want once the system is booted, and the desktop will usually show the same media ejection options for it that it would for any other removable device.

Comment: Thank you, the situation is #2, persistent storage on the USB. I don't think it's using the laptops RAM, although I'm unsure about this as it wasn't something that was asked during creating the boot drive. So essentially, as long as the system as turned off correctly, i'm always safe to remove the USB?

Comment: I think doing that thing could corrupt your USB.

Comment: @user3494604  If it's the second case, you have to shutdown _before_ you remove the USB drive, but otherwise yes.

Comment: For grub based distros you may eject if you load to ram by editing boot (grub) script during boot (replace 'quiet splash' with 'toram') before grub choice is made. BTW, Mint 18 Cinnamon distro takes about 6.5gb of memory this way. More details here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829917/can-i-boot-a-live-usb-fully-to-ram-allowing-me-to-remove-the-disk

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov The exact change in kernel parameters varies by distro, and it's actually not handled by GRUB, but by the initramfs.